# AWS4 signature in Node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

I'm trying to make a call to a private Amazon API with Javascript using the aws4 package, but I can't get it to work. I'm able to do the call successfully with Postman, but I'm trying to get it to work with code, and I'm failing.

Here is the postman screenshot:

[image]

And here is the code that is trying to replicate this:

```
request(aws4.sign({
    service: 'execute-api',
    region: 'us-east-1',
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://test.amazonAPI.com/test/doThing',
    body: load
  },
  {
    accessKeyId: tempCreds.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: tempCreds.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
    sessionToken: tempCreds.Credentials.SessionToken
  }))
```

And the error I'm currently getting:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:53:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:95:26)
```

Comment: If needed, you can also look at https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth.

Comment: The aws4 module seems to be a little bit rigid in this regard.  It's not clear (from a cursory glance) whether it has the necessary flexibility to work with an API Gateway URL.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're missing **hostname** in requestOptions.
Correct:

```
request(aws4.sign({
    hostname: 'test.amazonAPI.com',
    service: 'execute-api',
    region: 'us-east-1',
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://test.amazonAPI.com/test/doThing', // this field is not recommended in the document.
    body: load
  },
  {
    accessKeyId: tempCreds.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
    secretAccessKey: tempCreds.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
    sessionToken: tempCreds.Credentials.SessionToken
  }))
```

Reference: https://github.com/mhart/aws4